# how to pass multiple query strings in anchor tag?

Tags: asp.net, query-string, anchor

I want to pass multiple (more than one) query string in an anchor tag. Please let me know how can i ?
Like the following code its passing only one query string .

```
<a href='<%# Eval("Userid","EditUser.aspx?uid={0}") %>'>Text</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
<a href='EditUser.aspx?uid=<%# Eval("Userid")%>&other=<%# Eval("Other")%>'>Text</a>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a bit nicer than mine.

Comment: @Junaid you can ask yourself many such questions. Why not generate the url in the code behind? Why not using Sessions? etc. The only answer is that the OP didn't use them either, so to remain closest to the OP's code, neither did I.

Answer (score 0):

Separate them with ampersands, e.g.

```
<a href='EditUser.aspx?<%# Eval("Userid","uid={0}") %>&<%# Eval("FooId","Fooid={0}") %>'>Text</a>
```